# installation of netcdf in centos 5 or 6

Tags: centos, netcdf

I try to install netcdf in Centos 5 or 6. With Centos 5, I have typed

```
yum install netcdf-devel
```

I have the package netcdf-devel-3.6.3-1.i386
I have installed now also gcc gcc-c++ and gcc-gfortran

When I check if NetCDF-4/HDF-5 is enabled in this build, nc-config --has-nc4, it returns "no" and I need a yes

How can I enable it?

Comment: gcc and gfortran are needed to build netcdf, yum probably will install you all the dependencies, what else do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have built-in support for NetCDF-4/HDF-5, you must compile it appropriately. Please, refer to step-by-step instructions here: [Building NetCDF with NetCDF-4/HDF-5 support](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/netcdf-4/newdocs/netcdf-install/Quick-Instructions.html).